# Load an image that is in a subfolder using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a Pygame project in a folder called "Project". In it is my code and another folder named "Images". I want to load an image in the "Images" folder, but every time I try to do so, it comes with up an error, saying:

> pygame.error: Couldn't open Images/Frame1.png

I've tried using:

`image = pygame.image.load("Frame1.png")`,

`image = pygame.image.load("Images/Frame1.png")` , `image = pygame.image.load("Images/Frame1.png").convert()` and `image = pygame.image.load("Images/Frame1.png").convert_alpha()` .

Bare in mind that I've only imported the Pygame module.

All the codes above come up with the same error. I'm using Python v3.7.3 for Mac OSX. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: share your folder structure please

Comment: What is the working directory (`os.getcwd()`) and what is the directory of the python file when you run the code (`os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`)? The path has to be relative to the working directory and the working directory may be different to the directory of the file (or project).

Comment: The image's directory is `~/Python_Projects/Project/Images/Frame1.png`. My code's directory is `~/Python_Projects/Project/FirstProject.py`

Comment: Where are you executing from? Try running python and your script from "Project" folder.

Comment: @sombat92 try `import os` `print(os.getcwd())`. The path has to be relative to this directory. Or put `os.chdir( os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) )` at the begin of the code.

Comment: @Rabbid76 the output is above

Comment: @sombat92 No, it isn't. This is not the working directory.

Comment: @Rabbid76 The output of `print(os.getcwd())` is "/Users/mustafaabdillahi06/Python_Projects/Project" --- the output of `print(os.chdir( os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) ))` is "None"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try importing the os library and using `image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Images','Frame1.png')).convert_alpha()`. This worked for me when I did my own pygame project.

Answer (score 1):

The image filepath has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python file.

The difference can be investigated by:

```py
import os

currentWorkDir = os.getcwd()
print(currentWorkDir)

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(sourceFileDir)
```

See also [Import-related module attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes).

The current working directory can be changed by the application, to be the same as the python source file directory:

```
import os

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(sourceFileDir)
```

---

Instead of changing the working directory, you can also use an absolut path when you load the image file. Concatenate the directory of the file and the relative 
 image filepath:

```py
sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(sourceFileDir, "Images", "Frame1.png"))
```